# Why PHP include is working on local server and not on website

Tags: php, html, apache, include

*Problem Description in Brief:*
PHP script seems to work on my local web server when I 'include' it from the footer tag of my **index.html** file, but does not work when I upload it to my website.  Note that I have made sure that all paths are correct, and that the script file has its own php tags, etc.

*Problem Description in Detail:*
Yes, I am new to PHP scripting, and yes, variants of this question have probably been asked before.  The answers to a few of the questions I have read have noted the path of the php script files to be incorrect.  I have checked all paths and confirmed that they are indeed correct (including those on the web hosting server).  Furthermore, I have been successful in getting the script to work on my local server running Apache2 with PHP5, but have not been successful when uploading it to my website.

Essentially, I am trying to implement a hit counter script which I have acquired from a Stack Overflow post labelled [Visitors counter for simple web sites like Vinaora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138020/visitors-counter-for-simple-web-sites-like-vinaora).  The code that invokes the php script looks something like this....

```
  <footer>
    <!-- Execute Hit Counter Script -->
    <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/hitcounter.php'); ?>
  </footer>
```

For the likes of me, I cannot figure out why it does not work on the web hosting server.  I have tried other combinations of invoking the script like,

```
  <footer>
    <!-- Execute Hit Counter Script -->
    <?php include('./php/hitcounter.php'); ?>
  </footer>
```

and,

```
  <footer>
    <!-- Execute Hit Counter Script -->
    <?php include(dirname(__FILE__).'/php/hitcounter.php'); ?>
  </footer>
```

All combinations seem to work on my local web server, but not on the website!  Also note that, I have no problem invoking other PHP scripts using other methods (even on the web hosting server), eg.

```
    <form id="form-query" onsubmit="this.checkValidity();" action="./php/contact.php" method="post">
```

Any advice/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What errors are you seeing? Check the web server error log. If it works on one server but not another, your PHP itself should be fine - but paths or permissions are different.

Comment: @BotskoNet - I have checked the error logs of the website, and have confirmed that there are no errors.  This was the first suggestion that the technical staff of the web hosting providers made.

Comment: tried using index.php vs index.html?

Comment: @Ryan - Yes, I have also tried this, but nothing happened. As a sanity check, I will try to do this again, just in case I got it wrong....

Comment: When PHP fails to include a file it throws an error, unless you have PHP configured to ignore that error level. I would suggest running a debug statement to print the full filepath being used in the include, and use console or something to verify the file exists at that location.

Comment: Thanks BotskoNet and Ryan, I am currently trying to enable reporting of errors (as suggested by Tivie below), and changing the html file to a php file.  Will let you know how I go....

Comment: Success!  Renaming the index.html file to index.php has solved the problem!  Didn't have to enable reporting, nor insert 'included' code in the same file, but as a matter of course, and for future reference, I will enable reporting!  Thanks people!  This has solved my problem!

Comment: To all concerned.  I have been able to determine the initial cause of my problem.  Further investigation revealed that, it is possible to 'include' a php script from an html file (like I had done) if you configure the web server to do so by adding the line __<AddType application/x-httpd-php .html>__ in the __/etc/apache2/httpd.conf__ file. This is what I had done, and why it worked for me, and not my web hosting server.  Renaming the index file to __index.php__ resolved the web hosting server issue.  Whoever wants to copy and post this as the correct answer is more than welcome....

Answer (score 6):

Do you get any PHP error?

First of all, you need to activate error reporting.

Put this before including your file

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

PHP should tell you what's happening.

If you don't see anything, **change the filename index.html to index.php** and try again.

Comment: Thanks Tivie, changing the filename index.html to index.php has solved my problem!  Didn't have to enable reporting, although as a matter of course, and for future reference, I will do so.  Thanks, once again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe be you have used **"\"** in your include path

Wrong:

> `<?php include 'includes\header.php'; ?>`

You should use **"/"** to work.

Current:

> `<?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>`

Comment: you won't believe me but really this was the problem I had ... it couldn't find file with "\" ... just on server

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it might be dues to casing. check if you you uppercase in naming. on some servers Index.php is not equal to index.php

Answer (score -1):

You might try pasting the "include" code directly into the calling code. Maybe it's the included code itself that's misbehaving...

Answer (score -2):

You are doing completely incorrect thing in the first place.

> PHP script seems to work on my local web server when I 'include' it from the footer tag of my index.html

is just totally wrong

There is no such thing as embedding php file within html file (aside from mod_rewrite ...).
For PHP script to be interpreted you must have it (in 99% of cases) with php suffix. This way you allow PHP to distinguish it from regular PHP and send to php interpreter.

Put simply - create this file (a.html):

```
<body>
abcd<?php echo 'efgh';?>
</body>
```

and see the result in your browser - use .../a.html

What do you see?

> abcd

and not

> abcdefgh

On top you always have to have php not the other way around. Solve this or update your question if incorrect.

Comment: The question is correct.  Apparently, it is possible to 'include' a php script from an html file if you configure the web server to do so by adding the line __<AddType application/x-httpd-php .html>__ in the __/etc/apache2/httpd.conf__ file.  This is what I had done, and why it worked for me, and not my web hosting server.